# What to do with oracle JDeveloper 11g?

Tags: jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

I have installed Oracle JDevelper 11g Release 2 and added JHeadstart, following [simple instructions from Oracles website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jheadstart/devlic-087794.html?url=/technetwork/developer-tools/jheadstart/downloads/soft11g-174713.html)

Now I am stucked whith this screen and cant do anythig. I cannt close that "Buisness Components" screen or use JDeveloper.
[image]
I have some project in Jdeveloper that I need to modify and I cannot figure out how to import it to Eclipse, InteliJ or NetBeans so tryed to do it in Jdeveloper.

**I am using windows 8.1 64bit**

Comment: editet question, I cannot close that dialogue.. I can just end process to close JDeveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualize it all. Install same OS that project already runs on, and same JDeveloper and Jheadstart version, same JDKs, Oracle DB. etc.

Comment: More info like what? If someone is using "unpopular" IDE and framework and same legacy code and cant runt it. Why he shouldn't run that on same virtual environment project is developed on?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you installed a JHeadstart version that is aimed at JDeveloper 11 not 12.
I would suggest scrapping the JDeveloper directory and re-installing JDeveloper.

Comment: I have installed Jdeveloper 11 and appropriate version of JHeadstart http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jheadstart/jhs-jdev-supportmatrix-084434.html